# How can I record my weight using Siri?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, health.app

I want to use Siri to record my weight in Apple’s Health app. However, when I tell Siri “*Record my weight as X pounds*”, she responds “*I can’t answer that on your iPhone, but you can find it in the Health app*”.

Is it possible to record my weight in Apple’s Health app using Siri?

Comment: It is not possible yet, however a workflow using Apple's [Workflow app](https://workflow.is) may be able to help automate this, with a few instructions that I found on [9to5mac](https://9to5mac.com/2016/01/29/how-to-automate-weight-logging-iphone-health-app/) -- Best of Luck!

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly possible to say "Hey Siri. Record my weight as X pounds" currently (up to and including iOS 12).

However, there are two ways you can do this(-ish).

1. **Siri Suggestions**: if you launch the Health App (manually) and log your weight enough times, it will start showing up as a Siri Suggestion in Search. This will launch the Health App in the Weight section, and you can then log your weight manually.
2. **Shortcuts**: you can create a shortcut in the Shortcuts App. Use the Log Health Sample action, and select Body Measurements --> Weight. This will allow you to manually log your weight from a prompt. You can have it triggered by saying "Hey Siri. Record my weight". If you want you can make this more sophisticated with a combination of alerts/prompts and variables. It is not possible to launch a Shortcut *and* pass it input in the same statement (i.e. "Record my weight as X pounds", but you can launch the shortcut, and then have the shortcut use voice prompts and take voice input from you (note, you will have to convert text input to a number for the Health App). You will very quickly come to realise that Shortcuts *is not* a programming language, and gets clunky very fast. It's ugly (and fragile!), but it works (except when it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

In the current beta of iOS 12 you can easily set that up.

If you log your weight enough times it will eventually show up in the following place:

You go into Settings -> Siri & Search -> More Shortcuts -> Log Weight (find via search if necessary). I use the voice command "Log weight" to trigger it. Works as expected.

Edit: So you wanted to log the weight all in one command, my suggestion merely triggers the right input in the Health app, you then have to manually add the weight.

In the future, I suspect one could solve this by going through the Siri workflow app, but that App is not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Maybe Apple will add the Health domain to Siri in a future update.

The best thing to do is request this feature with the feedback forms from Apple: https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html